# Tangram scene.load() failed to load blob error after migrating to JS v3.1

Tags: heremaps, tangram

recently in our project we have upgraded to Here latest Javascript v3.1 but after migration we are getting Tangram scene.load() failed to load blob error in developer console. Can anyone help me on this topic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hcrr.png)

Why am I getting this error in developer console.